# Element id of two duplicate class names based on click

Tags: jquery

I have two divs with different ids but with the same classname. Example: Window1 & Window2...

```
<div id="Window1" class="name">
   <span id="Admin"></span>
</div>

<div id="Window2" class="name">
   <span id="Admin"></span>
</div>
```

I want to get the element id of "name" when I click on id "Admin". Obviously the var solution is wrong below but want to set up something close to this...

```
var Window_id = $(".name").attr("id");
```

I hope this explains what I am trying to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: IDs must be unique. You should be using valid HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you can't have two objects with the same ID.  So you can't have two objects with `id="Admin"`.  You will have to give each one a different ID or use a common class name (or both).  So you could change it to this:

```
<div id="Window1" class="name">
   <span id="Admin1" class="admin"></span>
</div>

<div id="Window2" class="name">
   <span id="Admin2" class="admin"></span>
</div>
```

And, then use this jQuery to handle the click and get the id of the parent of the clicked object:

```
$(".admin").click(function() {
    var parentId = $(this).parent().attr("id");
});
```

or, a little more efficiently using a little less jQuery:

```
$(".admin").click(function() {
    var parentId = this.parentNode.id
});
```

My favorite option would actually be this because it's a little more robust against some HTML changes (like if a new container div was introduced around the span):

```
$(".admin").click(function() {
    var parentId = $(this).closest(".name").attr("id");
});
```

`.parent()` or `.parentNode` used in the first two options go up exactly one level in the DOM hieararchy.

`.closest(".name")` used in the third option goes up the parent hierarchy as far as needed until it finds a parent that matches the passed in selector.  It's a little more powerful and more likely to make sure you get the parent you want, even if the HTML changes a little bit.  Not always required, but worth knowing about.

Answer (score 0):

Use this inside the `click` handler.

```
$(this).parent().attr("id");
```

`$(this).parent()` will get the parent element which is the div with class `name` and the `attr('id')` will get the id of the div element.

Side note: Ideally the element ids on the page should be unique which your markup don't have.

I would suggest instead of having an `id` to Admin `span`, have a common class and use class selector to select them. Something like this.

HTML

```
<div id="Window1" class="name">
   <span class="admin"></span>
</div>

<div id="Window2" class="name">
   <span class="admin"></span>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.admin').click(function(){
   var parentId = $(this).parent().attr("id");

   //Or
   var parentId = $(this).parent()[0].id;

   //Or
   var parentId = $(this).closest('.name').attr('id');

   //Or
   var parentId = $(this).closest('.name')[0].id;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not give same Id for 2 elements. You are giving the same id for bothe spans.

If you have differnt ids for span and same class name, To get the parent id, you can do this

```
var parentID=$(".spanClassName").parent().attr("id");
```

Assuming spanClassName is the classname you use for both spans

```
$(".spanClassName").click(function(){    
     var parentID=  $(this).parent().attr("id");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two spans with the same id "Admin". Try this

```
<div id="Window1" class="name">
    <span>Admin</span>
</div>

<div id="Window2" class="name">
    <span>Admin</span>
</div>

$('.name span').click( function( e ){
    console.log( $(this).parent('.name').attr('id') );
});
```

Comment: This is an interesting way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="Window1" class="name">
   <span class="Admin">a</span>
</div>

<div id="Window2" class="name">
   <span class="Admin">a</span>
</div>
<script>
$('.Admin').on('click', function(){
  var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
  alert(id);
});
</script>
```

You need to use class 'Admin' because you have more than on element with id 'Admin' other wise.